# Best way to measure overhead by using sync methods

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'am working on nodeJS app that was written using sync method all over it. Mainly for working with files and for spawninch child processes. I need to **measure the overhead because of blocking main thread**. What is the best way to measure this?
I tried using `Date.now` before and after function but it gives me unreliable results.
It might be important that the **app is run by `node main.js arguments`**

Answer (score 1):

Use Node.js built in API

https://nodejs.org/api/perf_hooks.html

Copied from docs

```js
const { PerformanceObserver, performance } = require('perf_hooks');

const obs = new PerformanceObserver((items) => {
  console.log(items.getEntries()[0].duration);
  performance.clearMarks();
});
obs.observe({ entryTypes: ['measure'] });

performance.mark('A');
doSomeLongRunningProcess(() => {
  performance.mark('B');
  performance.measure('A to B', 'A', 'B');
});
```